# Function for wrapping variables as functions in a class in Python

Tags: python-2.7

If I have a a class, taking certain parameters being either functions or numbers, I can wrap the numbers as functions

```
class Example:
    def __init__(self, var):
        if isinstance(var, (float,int)): # Check if the variable is a number
            self.var = lambda t: var     # Wrap it as a function
        elif callable(var):
            self.var = var
```

Say I have class taking many such parameters, how can I make a function for wrapping a variable (or fix it another way)?

Comment: Why not just move that logic out to a `@staticmethod` or function `make_callable`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I'm learn Python now, so I might be missing something, but how can I store the variables in the instance. Would not a function, `make_callable(self, var)`, written as in the question store the callable object in a variable named `var`?

Comment: You would write it such that you can use it e.g. `self.var = make_callable(var)`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Yes, but my problem is when there are many arguments. To generalized it, consider the constructor `def __init__(self, *var)`.

Comment: In that case, how would you be assigning the parameters to attributes? `self.vars = map(make_callable, var)`?

Comment: Yup! That is what I was thinking unless there is a better way...

Comment: Better by what measure? You still haven't described what you're trying to achieve in the broader sense, so it's impossible to say.